# Unable to access data from service

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement where I want to retrieve a JSON object from the server. Below are two versions which do not work -

Version 1

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
  var authMap = [];
  $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data){this.authMap = data});
}]);
```

Version 2

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
  var authMap = [];
  $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data){authMap = data});

  var getAuthMap = function(){return authMap};
}]);
```

In version one I am injecting the service into my controller and accessing it as authorization.authMap, it returns an empty [].

In version two, I am accessing it as authorization.getAuthMap(). Here it gives me an error that no such method is defined on the object ?

What is wrong with both the methods ?

Answer (score 2):

Just make the variables part of that services scope

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
    var authorizationScope = this;
    authorizationScope.authMap = [];
    $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data){authorizationScope .authMap = data});
}]);
```

Version 2

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
    var authorizationScope = this;
    authorizationScope.authMap = [];
    $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data){authorizationScope.authMap = data});

    authorizationScope.getAuthMap = function(){return authorizationScope.authMap};
}]);
```

That way in your controller when you inject it you can access that variable or function

```
function myController($scope, authorization){
    authorization.authMap //this is how you would access the variable here
    authorization.getAuthMap(); //this is how you would access the function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should expose your function.
2. You need to understand that $http is an asynchronuous call. Easiest way to fix is to return the $http promise to your controller and resolve the data there.

So:

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
  return {
     getAuthMap : function(){
        return $http.get('/authmap');
     }
  };
}]);
```

In your controller:

```
authorization.getAuthMap().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

If the data is complex and should be processed within your service, you could use service $q in your service and return its promise to your controller. This makes the service slightly more complex:

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

  var authMap;

  return {
     getAuthMap : function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        promise.then(function() {
           if (!authMap) {
              $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data) {
                 var changedData = data;
                 // do sth with data
                 authMap = changedData;

                 deferred.resolve(changedData);
              });
           } else {
              deferred.resolve(authMap)
           }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
     }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for the great reply. I would just like to retrieve the data once from the server and store it in a var internally in the service. This way the same var can be accessed by different controllers. The first solution wont work, any other simpler solution?

Comment: You could use a cache using $cacheFactory. I've updated my answer.

Comment: On second thoughts, you don't need a cache. Just use a private variable. I've edited my answer. The map is retrieved via http get only once. Up vote, please :)

Answer (score 1):

You already asked about version 1 in another post, and it was answered there: [Unable to set a class var in $http callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970981/unable-to-set-a-class-var-in-http-callback/13971560)

To summarize: the success() and error() methods are called with the function context (i.e., `this`) set to the global context (i.e., `window`).  So `this.authMap = data` stores the data in window.authMap, rather than in your service.  You need to create a closure (by defining a local variable and setting it to `this`) and then use that variable in the success() function:

```js
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
  this.authMap = [];
  var self = this;
  $http.get('/authmap')
     .success(function(data){
        self.authMap = data
     })
     .error(function(data, status){
        alert('Unable to authorize')
        console.log(status)
     })
}]);
```

Version 2 has two problems:

1. Same problem as version 1
2. You are using service(), so the body of the service function needs to be a JavaScript constructor function (because Angular will instantiate the service by essentially calling `new` on the constructor function).  So, public properties (including functions/methods) need to be defined on `this`:

```js
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
   this.authMap = [];
   this.getAuthMap = function(){ return this.authMap };
   var self = this;
   $http.get('/authmap')
      .success(function(data){
         self.getAuthMap = data
      })
      .error(function(data, status){
         alert('Unable to authorize')
         console.log(status)
      })
}]);
```

If you want to keep authMap private, use a factory() instead:

```js
app.factory("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
   var authMap = [];         // private data
   $http.get('/authmap')
      .success(function(data){
         authMap = data
      })
      .error(function(data, status){
         alert('Unable to authorize')
         console.log(status)
      })
   return {
      getAuthMap: function() { return authMap };
   }
}]);
```