# Unable to set a class var in $http callback

Tags: angularjs

In the example below I am trying to set a variable defined in the below service, in the success callback. I am unable to set the var authMap in the service. What is happening here and how do I do it?

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
  this.authMap = [];
  $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data){this.authMap = data});

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new scope is created in your anonymous callback function, so `this` is different.
You could do something like:

```
app.service("authorization", ['$http', function($http){
  this.authMap = [];
  var that = this;
  $http.get('/authmap').success(function(data){ that.authMap = data });
}]);
```

Comment: I added an error() method to get() (i.e., ....error(function(data) { console.log(this === window) }) and the console reports `true`.  So the success() and error() methods are called with the function context (i.e., `this`) set to the global context (i.e., `window`).  Also, for clarification, since "scope" often makes Angular developers think of Angular scopes, @maxdec is not referring to an Angular scope here.  The "that" variable creates the necessary closure so that the success function's JavaScript scope chain includes the service object.

Comment: Exactly I'm not talking about Angular scope but JavaScript scope.